# JSON string wrapped in double quotes - Can't write out values from JSON string - (asp.net webservice to JSON to jQuery)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asmx

Im trying to use a asp.net webservice to send JSON data, which it gets from a MySql database, to a web app, which uses jQuery to display the data sent through JSON.

My webservice method looks like this:

```
[WebMethod(Description = "yet another test .....")]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetCustomerByIDTRY()
{
string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["my_domain_mysql"].ConnectionString;
MySqlConnection connection1 = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Vet_Users.FirstName, Vet_Users.LastName, Vet_Users.UserID, Vet_Customer.CusID FROM Vet_Users JOIN Vet_Customer ON Vet_Users.UserID=Vet_Customer.UserID");
DataSet CusIDDataSet = new DataSet();
MySqlDataAdapter CusIDDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
CusIDDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = connection1;
CusIDDataAdapter.Fill(CusIDDataSet, "reading");
connection1.Close();
StringBuilder JSON = new StringBuilder();
JSON.Append("{");
JSON.Append("\"NumberOfCustomers\":\"" + CusIDDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString() + "\", ");
JSON.Append("\"Customer\":[");
foreach (DataRow rs in CusIDDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
JSON.Append("{");
JSON.Append("\"CusID\":\"" + rs["CusID"].ToString() + "\",");
JSON.Append("\"FirstName\":\"" + rs["FirstName"].ToString() + "\",");
JSON.Append("\"LastName\":\"" + rs["LastName"].ToString() + "\",");
if (JSON.ToString().EndsWith(","))
JSON = JSON.Remove(JSON.Length - 1, 1);
JSON.Append("},");
}
if (JSON.ToString().EndsWith(","))
JSON = JSON.Remove(JSON.Length - 1, 1);
JSON.Append("]}");
return JSON.ToString();
}
```

The JSON comes back like this:

```
Object { d="{"NumberOfCustomers":"1...","LastName":"Woods"}]}"}
```

Its wrapped in a "d", cause of asp.net 3.5+ security issue.
(http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again/)

But my JSON comes wrapped in double quotes, and i can't figure out why.

```
"{"NumberOfCustomers":"15", "Customer":[{"CusID":"1","FirstName":"Ina","LastName":"Williamson"},{"CusID":"2","FirstName":"Hyacinth","LastName":"Brady"},{"CusID":"3","FirstName":"Coby","LastName":"Shannon"}]}"
```

This is the jQuery function, that im trying to get working:

`function FinalTest() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    data: "{}", 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json", 
    success: function (data) {
    alert(eval(data.d.NumberOfCustomers));
    }
    });
    };`

Comment: Try a datatype of Jsonp instead.

Comment: First of all web service can't directly return a Json format, for that you have to make string like Json and when you to call your web service it's actually return string not Json. however you can try $j.parseJSON(response); in sucess event

Comment: @brumScouse it just tells me that there was a syntax error then.

Comment: @Rachit Patel Can you write that as an answer?
I had tried parseJSON before, but somehow it worked this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't manually serialize JSON. The framework will handle that for you. More info here: http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-services-mistake-manual-json-serialization/

Do something like this and `JavaScriptSerializer` will handle building valid JSON for you:

```
public class Customer {
  public string CusID { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod(Description = "yet another test .....")]
[ScriptMethod]
public object GetCustomerByIDTRY() {
  string connString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["my_domain_mysql"].ConnectionString;
  MySqlConnection connection1 = new MySqlConnection(connString);
  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Vet_Users.FirstName, Vet_Users.LastName, Vet_Users.UserID, Vet_Customer.CusID FROM Vet_Users JOIN Vet_Customer ON Vet_Users.UserID=Vet_Customer.UserID");
  DataSet CusIDDataSet = new DataSet();
  MySqlDataAdapter CusIDDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  CusIDDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = connection1;
  CusIDDataAdapter.Fill(CusIDDataSet, "reading");
  connection1.Close();

  var customers = new List<Customer>();

  foreach (DataRow rs in CusIDDataSet.Tables[0].Rows) {
    customers.Add(new Customer {
      CusID = rs["CusID"].ToString(),
      FirstName = rs["FirstName"].ToString(),
      LastName = rs["LastName"].ToString()
    });
  }

  return new {
    NumberOfCustomers = CusIDDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString(),
    Customer = customers
  };
}
```

Comment: A week of trial and error trying to implement this webservice with JSON + outputting the data and reading/researching about it, made me just go with the solution that worked. I did cross ways with something similar to this, but newer made it work properly, but that one looks solid. Thnx alot.